# Firebase firestore .QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this weird problem that never occured to me in any of my firestore apps,I have this Recyclerview where i want to display image and text from my firestore, and I am getting the following error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference

This is how my data in firestore is present:

[image]
The following is my Activity class

```java
package rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.view;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.R;
import rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.adapter.BreakfastAdapter;
import rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.model.ContentsBreakfast;

public class BreakfastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private static final String TAG="BreakfastActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_breakfast);


        RecyclerView recbrf = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec_brf);
        recbrf.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        final List<ContentsBreakfast> breakfastList = new ArrayList();
        recbrf.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        final BreakfastAdapter adapterb = new BreakfastAdapter(breakfastList, getApplicationContext());
        recbrf.setAdapter(adapterb);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
      db.collection("breakfast").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e!=null){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Error:"+e.getMessage());
                }
                for (DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                        //String title = doc.getDocument().getString("title");

                        ContentsBreakfast bfname= doc.getDocument().toObject(ContentsBreakfast.class);
                        breakfastList.add(bfname);
                        adapterb.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }}
        });


    }
}
```

This is my Adapter class of Recyclerview

```java
package rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Protocol;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.R;
import rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.model.ContentsBreakfast;
import rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.view.RecipeView;

public class BreakfastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BreakfastAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<ContentsBreakfast> breakfastlist = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public BreakfastAdapter(List<ContentsBreakfast> breakfastlist, Context context) {
        this.breakfastlist = breakfastlist;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BreakfastAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.breakfast_card, parent, false);
        return new BreakfastAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.brfname.setText(breakfastlist.get(position).getBfname());
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.browser)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(breakfastlist.get(position).getBfimg())
                .apply(options)
                .into(holder.brfimg);
        holder.card_brf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, RecipeView.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return breakfastlist.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView brfname;
        public ImageView brfimg;
        public CardView card_brf;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card_brf = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.brf_card);
            brfname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brf_name);
            brfimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brf_image);

        }
    }}
```

The following code contains my Model class

```java
package rimapps.appslet.lchfmalayalam.model;

public class ContentsBreakfast {
    int bfimg;
    String bfname;

    public int getBfimg() {
        return bfimg;
    }

    public void setBfimg(int bfimg) {
        this.bfimg = bfimg;
    }

    public String getBfname() {
        return bfname;
    }

    public void setBfname(String bfname) {
        this.bfname = bfname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Mohsen I know about null pointerException errors.the problem is I cant find one here

Comment: Have you checked this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350819/4409113

Comment: That wouldnt help me @Mohsen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/EventListener.html#onEvent(T,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException)) for `onEvents`, they say:

> `onEvent` will be called with the new value **or** the error if an error occurred. It's guaranteed that **exactly one of value or error will be non-null**.
>
> Parameters:
>
> *value*   The value of the event. null if there was an error.
>
> *error*   The error if there was error. null otherwise.

So it seems that `onEvent` **either** gets an error **or** a query snapshot. So you need an `if... then... else` in your code:

```
public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e!=null){
        Log.d(TAG,"Error:"+e.getMessage());
    }
    else {
        for (DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                ContentsBreakfast vidtitle= doc.getDocument().toObject(ContentsBreakfast.class);
                breakfastList.add(vidtitle);
                adapterb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
});
```